# Deserialize JSON to Nested Model

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a model like below:

```
public class YourInformationInputModel
    {
        public YourInformationInputModel()
        {           
            PrimaryBuyerInformation = new PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel();          
        }

        public PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel PrimaryBuyerInformation { get; set; } 

        public bool TermsCondition { get; set; }
    }
```

PrimaryBuyerInputModel like below:

```
public class PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel
    {

        [Required]
        public string BuyerFirstName { get; set; }

        public string BuyerMiddleInitial { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string BuyerLastName { get; set; }
    }
```

and when I am submitting my form then I am getting JSON like below:

```
{
  "PrimaryBuyerInformation.BuyerFirstName": "Sunil",
  "PrimaryBuyerInformation.BuyerMiddleInitial": "",
  "PrimaryBuyerInformation.BuyerLastName": "Choudhary",
  "TermsCondition": "true"
}
```

When I am trying to deserialize this json the `TermsCondition` property successfully done, but the property of `PrimaryBuyerInformation` is not mapped.

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourInformationInputModel>(json);
```

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: How did you submit and serialize a model?

Comment: the json is coming from FromData

Comment: while deserializing it will consider field as string PrimaryBuyerInformation.BuyerFirstName

Comment: @viveknuna yes you are right, is there any way to deserilize this ?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take a cue from the code below, i tested it and you should be able to get your value as request. This solves the issue of you trying to access the property you have mapped in a dot property name format.

Instead your object should be nested in a curly brace showing that the other property belongs to PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel which is another object entirely.

Best Regards,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{'PrimaryBuyerInformation': {'buyerFirstName': 'Sunil','buyerMiddleInitial': '','buyerLastName': 'Choudhary'},'termsCondition': false}";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourInformationInputModel>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.PrimaryBuyerInformation.BuyerFirstName);


    }
}
public class YourInformationInputModel
    {
        public YourInformationInputModel()
        {           
            PrimaryBuyerInformation = new PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel();          
        }

        public PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel PrimaryBuyerInformation { get; set; } 

        public bool TermsCondition { get; set; }
    }

public class PrimaryBuyerInformationInputModel
    {
        public string BuyerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string BuyerMiddleInitial { get; set; }
        public string BuyerLastName { get; set; }
    }
```